# Setting a from address in SingleEmailMessage not by organisation wide email address

Tags: apex, email, singleemailmessage

I have a requirement where the ‘from address’ need to be changed . According to business logic cannot use “Organization wide email address”

When ever the record is updated , From address should display Record Owner Name not the one who updated the record .

Code :

```
     mail.setReplyTo(record owner email);
     mail.setSenderDisplayName('record owner name');
```

Error : In ‘From Address’  It should display only the record owner name  not the one who updated the record**([mailto :xyz@salesforce.com])**

From: record owner name **[mailto :xyz@salesforce.com]** 
Sent: Friday, February 19, 2016 11:27 AM

Comment: so what is the real issue here? -- you can fetch the record owner name and email via `owner.name` and `owner.email` relationships using SOQL

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Salesforce article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000232863&language=en_US) on "**Setting a 'from' address in SingleEmailMessage**".

To do this you must first set up a dedicated email address by navigating to Setup -> Administration Setup -> Email Administration -> Organization-Wide Addresses menu.

Once you have created an org-wide address (note that Salesforce will require you to confirm the address prior to using it, so if you're going to be sending things from a junk address it would be wise to set up a catch-all mailbox so you receive the confirmation email), grab the Id from the URL and use the setOrgWideEmailAddressId(Id)method on your instance of Messaging.SingleEmailMessage.
If you want to avoid hard-coding an Id, after creating your Org-Wide Address you can query them:

```
OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'doNotReply@blahblah.com'];
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
if ( owea.size() > 0 ) {
    mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
}
```

Source - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000232863&language=en_US

Comment: I thought he said he couldn't use org wide default email?

Comment: Yes without using org wide default email. .. Is there any way ?

Comment: Why there is a negative vote? I know in the question it was mentioned. But my intention is to show how you can create multiple 'Organization wide email address' and use them as per your need.