# Developer's Email Address appearing when sending email via Apex

Tags: apex, email

An external developer created apex to send an email to users when a form is submitted.  The email works, but the sender email address that shows in the email appears to be the developer's email.  I don't know how to change this.  The correct ReplyTo address is set and the correct Sender DisplayName shows, but the developer's email address appears as the sender's email when you look closely at it.  Also, the guy's picture shows up in Gmail with the message because he has that type of address.  I don't want my users to see a person's picture that doesn't work at our company.

Email method from comments:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mailToSend = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
mailToSend.setToAddresses(emailsAddress); 
mailToSend.setReplyTo('membership@niimbl.org'); 
mailToSend.setSenderDisplayName('NIIMBL'); mailToSend.saveAsActivity = false; 
mailToSend.setSubject('Membership Information'); 
mailToSend.setPlainTextBody('Thank you for contacting NIIMBL! A member of the 
NIIMBL team will contact you shortly.'); Messaging.sendEmail(new 
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mailToSend});
```

Comment: Is it a scheduled job? More detail is needed here.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122253/setting-a-from-address-in-singleemailmessage-not-by-organisation-wide-email-addr

Comment: This is not a scheduled job.  It is apex that is run when a form is submitted.  I just set an OWD address & it wasn't used by the code.  Below is a key piece of the code.  Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Not sure how to paste chunk of code that is large...working on it.

Comment: Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mailToSend = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mailToSend.setToAddresses(emailsAddress);
        mailToSend.setReplyTo('membership@niimbl.org');
        mailToSend.setSenderDisplayName('NIIMBL');
        mailToSend.saveAsActivity = false;
        mailToSend.setSubject('Membership Information');
        mailToSend.setPlainTextBody('Thank you for contacting NIIMBL!  A member of the NIIMBL team will contact you shortly.');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mailToSend});

Comment: This is what is showing in the header of the email:

Comment: NIIMBL via 5yyouxklwl6hz9.6a-tfmfuaq.na50.bnc.salesforce.com  -> this is not my OWD address

Comment: The developer doesn't even have an account in my instance.  I am not sure how his email is showing up when this code is run.

Comment: Could an email address be associated with an email template?

Comment: I am thinking it has to do with the creator of the controller file...I have different code that I created that runs via the email service.  When I look at the sender of those emails it shows as my name.  They are automatically triggered - I am not logged in when it happens.  So...how do I remove the developer's association with my code if that is what is going on?

Comment: I am thinking that the component that contains the form in question needs to be recreated under my id.  Is there a way to clone a component?

Comment: Pasting code or any further details directly related to the question is not recommended. Please have your question edited to reflect all these details so that it helps everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created an OWD email address & set it in my code before sending the email.  It is still interesting that it appears the original developer's email is used if an OWD is not set.

Comment: If your form is being submitted via some kind of web service integration, that external system may be authenticating as your original developer, making him/her the running user when the email send goes off.